# From dot product and scalar multiplication and viceversa: what is the structure that moves between them?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a dot product $X$
I have a scalar multiplication $Y$

I want to understand what structure is there if I want to go from dot product $X$ to scalar multiplication $Y$ and viceversa, go from scalar multiplication $Y$ to dot product $X$

Can you provide me an example, please ?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What do you mean "go from" scalar multiplication to dot product?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The two are completely different operations.

Comment: viz., a dot product maps two vectors to a scalar, whereas a scalar multiplication maps a scalar and a vector to a vector

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I wish to understand if exist an underlying structure between these 2 different operations

Comment: @Andrei yes, but if are completely different operations what makes them different and distinct from each other?

Comment: these operations could be defined when there is a vector space

Comment: Yes, but I want to limit this distinction only to these 2 operations, in particular. Also the cross product is defined when there is a vector space, so it cannot be a generic vector space to differentiate them from what is scalar multiplication from the dot product

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think he's asking for an isomorphism.

Comment: Suppose you have two vector spaces $U,\, V$ over a field $F,$ it seems what you want is a map $F×U\to U×V$ defined as $au=u\cdot v.$ If so, it doesn't make sense for most vector spaces $U$ as the right is always a scalar, and the left a vector. You can find such a map only in the case when $U=F.$

Comment: @Allawonder yes, mm..but is sufficient only to write that vector space $U$ is a field $F$ or is need to demostrate this? Because if before you start from 2 vector spaces over **one** field, if I set $U=F$ then it's like we have *one* vector space V over **two** fields

Comment: I know also this: a map between two vector spaces over different fields cannot be linear, but can be semilinear . In this case there exists an homomorphism between the two fields $ϕ:F1→F2$ that is also an homomorphism between the multiplicative groups of the fields. But if I set $U=F$ what type of map is it? Is semilinear? Is an homomorphism group?

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about a real vector space $V$. The elements $x$ of $V$, called *vectors*, can be added and subtracted, and they can be stretched by real factors $\lambda$, whereby the stretched vector $x$ is written $\lambda x$. These operations satisfy certain rules codified in the axioms of a *vector space*.

Sometimes the operation 
$${\mathbb R}\times V\to V, \qquad(\lambda, x)\mapsto \lambda x$$
that multiplies a given $x\in V$ with a scalar $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$ is called *scalar multiplication*.

Now some vector spaces $V$ are equipped with a bilinear function
$$\psi:\quad V\times V\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$$
whose value for any pair $(x,y)$ is a real number, or a scalar. The definition of such a *scalar product* $\psi$ requires additional data not inherent in the setup of the vector space $V$. These data consist of a symmetric matrix $G$ that changes with the basis of $V$.

If $V={\mathbb R}^n$ then $V$ has the distinguished basis $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ (with $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)$, etcetera). The *standard scalar product* on this $V$ has $G=I_n$ as defining symmetric matrix, so that we have
$$x\cdot y=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\, y_i$$
in this case.